# Problems with Hairpin NAT when sharing multiple services on a public IP?

Tags: nat, sonicwall

Our Internet line is configured as follows (IP addresses are simplified placeholders, but it's the same layout):

```
Subnet:              192.168.200.0/24
Default gateway:     192.168.200.1
Public interface IP: 192.168.200.2
SMTP:                192.168.200.2:25 (translates to 192.168.0.2)
Email web interface: 192.168.200.2:80 (translates to 192.168.0.2)
VPN device:          192.168.200.3:80 (translates to 192.168.0.3)
My computer:         192.168.0.50
```

Notice that the main public IP is NATted to several services on a server on the back-end, and that different devices utilize the same port for different services.

My problem is this: I'm having trouble with NAT reflection (accessing a device on my LAN from its public interface). From what I understand, I need to translate my computer's IP to the public IP, so the router will properly un-NAT my packets and send them back to me. However, I've tried just about every combination of NAT rules I can think of and it still doesn't work for me. We did move to a new location recently, and one of the only things changed in our Sonicwall was the settings for our WAN interface. **Are there any problems with the configuration above that are interfering with my attempt to configure NAT reflection?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had NAT loopback configured correctly, but there was a bug in SonicWALL's implementation of 802.1p QoS that was causing loopback traffic to be dropped. There was nothing wrong with the IP configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Your search term is "NAT hairpin".  I don't use SonicWall, but I found this video which seems to describe how to do it:

http://www.firewalls.com/videos/video/sonicwall-loopback-nat-policy.html

Comment: It's behind a paywall :\

Comment: Ah, crap.  Sorry.  I was just doing the "NAT hairpin Sonicwall" search and came across that.

Comment: He's right though.  You'll want to add a NAT rule that translates the source from "Firewalled Subnets" to "WAN IP".